# Catch exceptions with logging in console using Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

There is the following code:

```
  if Rails.env.production?    
    rescue_from ArgumentError, ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid do |exp| 
      render_error(message: t('exceptions.incorrect_request_params'))
    end
  end

  def render_error(params)
    @error_message = params[:message]
    render 'shared/error', status: params[:status] || :bad_request
  end
```

I catch the exceptions using this code, it works good, but when it happens I can't see the reason of this event in console - I just see something like this:

```
I, [2015-08-30T05:55:24.068366 #24617]  INFO -- :   Rendered shared/error.json.jbuilder (0.2ms)
I, [2015-08-30T05:55:24.068615 #24617]  INFO -- : Completed 503 Service Unavailable in 289ms (Views: 1.1ms | ActiveRecord: 2.1ms)
```

How can I render template and also to write in console? Thanks in advance!

Comment: show how you defined this method render_error ?

Comment: So, you rendered the error page, that is why it came also in the console. Now what is your confusion ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Rails logger to log to your console 
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html#the-logger

you'll do something like this

```
def render_error(params)
    @error_message = params[:message]
    logger.error(@error_message)
    render 'shared/error', status: params[:status] || :bad_request
end
```

Answer (score -1):

```
if Rails.env.production?    
  rescue_from ArgumentError, ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid do |exp| 
    Rails.logger.error(exp)
    render_error(message: t('exceptions.incorrect_request_params'))
  end
end
```

Comment: Could you please explain your answer? That way, those who come across this question will understand why your solution works rather than being tempted to copy/paste it without knowing how to apply the same techniques in future.